# How would I retrieve parent categories in a mysql query?

Tags: sql, mysql

My goal is to achieve a list of parent categories from a nested category the easiest way. Say if I had a site that sold a variety of different products, one of which is a quad core pentium. A feature that I'd be able to display on my webpage is as follows:

Electronics > Computers > CPU's > Intel > Intel Quad Core

The category table that I had in mind is:

id,
parent_id,
description

Doing a recursive process on the parent_id seems tedious. Is there a preferred way of doing this? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).

The part you're probably interested in most right now is this:

> **Retrieving a Single Path**
>
> With the nested set model, we can retrieve a single path without having multiple self-joins.